# Entity Framework Delete Object Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

i am getting "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager". while Deleting object.

here is codes ;

```
//first i am filling listview control.
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirebirdEntity asa = new FirebirdEntity();

        ObjectQuery<NEW_TABLE> sorgu = asa.NEW_TABLE;

        foreach (var item in sorgu)
        {
            ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem();
            list.Text = item.AD;
            list.SubItems.Add(item.SOYAD);
            list.Tag = item;
            listView1.Items.Add(list);

        }
//than getting New_table entity from listview's tag property.
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            using (FirebirdEntity arama = new FirebirdEntity())
            {

               NEW_TABLE del = (NEW_TABLE)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
               arama.DeleteObject(del);
               arama.SaveChanges();


            }}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) the object to the `ObjectContext`. Try:

```
NEW_TABLE del = (NEW_TABLE)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
arama.Attach(del);
arama.DeleteObject(del);
arama.SaveChanges();
```

Attached objects are tracked by the `ObjectContext`. This is needed for performing deletes and updates. You can read more about [attaching objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) on MSDN.

Edit to clarify attach/detach:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    FirebirdEntity asa = new FirebirdEntity();

    ObjectQuery<NEW_TABLE> sorgu = asa.NEW_TABLE;
    foreach (var item in sorgu) {
        asa.Detach(item);
        // add to listView1
    }
}
```

Also, you should wrap your use of `ObjectContext`s in `using` blocks.

Comment: i m getting this error now ; An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Comment: You need to detach it from the ObjectContext that provided you the entity. Call ObjectContext.Detach with the object as a parameter.

Comment: now i am Gettin error like "object can not detached cuz its not atached". :(

Comment: there is only one Objectcontext and than i am tryin to attach-deattach .. is there any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. You need to detach the entity from the instance of the ObjectContext that provided you the entity before attaching it to another instance for deletion. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

In your method "Form1_Load" you create a FIRST instance of your "FirebirdEntity" context an fill the ListViewItem with entities selected from this context

In your method "button3_Click" you create a NEW, SECOND instance of your "FirebirdEntity" context. Then you try to delete an entity in this SECOND context, which was selected in the FIRST context.

Use the same instance of your context in both of your methods and everything will work fine.

(Alternatively you can select the entity you want to delete a from your SECOND context and then delete this entity instead of the origin one)

Answer (score 3):

I ran a linq query within my DomainService methods and then deleted from the result, so while the first snippet below failed with error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager", the second snippet worked.

```
public void DeleteSharedDoc(SharedDocs shareddoc)
{
       this.ObjectContext.SharedDocs.DeleteObject(shareddoc);
}
```

This worked:

```
public void DeleteSharedDoc(SharedDocs shareddoc)
{
var query = (from w in this.ObjectContext.SharedDocs
            where w.UserShareName == shareddoc.UserShareName
            && w.UserShareUsersEmail == shareddoc.UserShareUsersEmail
            && w.DocumentId == shareddoc.DocumentId
            select w).First();
this.ObjectContext.SharedDocs.DeleteObject(query);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

usually for a delete in database i use this sort of linq query, always works unless you got a foreign key restraint:

```
int id = convert.toint32(some text field from the page);
entity data = new entity();
var del = (from record in data.records 
          where record.id == id
          select record).FirstOrDefault();
data.deleteObject(del);
data.saveChanges();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assume I have an object called Department, with a surrogatekey DepartmentUUID

DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
    ( 
          DepartmentUUID [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL 
        , DepartmentName varchar(24) not null
        , CreateDate smalldatetime not null 
    )
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Department PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (DepartmentUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DepartmentName_Unique UNIQUE (DepartmentName) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Department_DepartmentUUID] DEFAULT ( NEWSEQUENTIALID() ) FOR DepartmentUUID
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Department] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Department_CreateDate] DEFAULT ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) FOR CreateDate
GO
```

Now for the Entity Framework code.   The important parts are:
1.  Using the AttachTo method.
2.  Creating a temporary object, and setting the primary-key value of it.  (surrogate key).

```
public int DeleteDepartment(Guid departmentUUID)
{

    int returnValue = 0;

    Department holder = new Department();
    holder.DepartmentUUID = departmentUUID; // DepartmentUUID is the primary key of this object (entity in the db)

    using (MyContectObject context = new MyContectObject())
    {
        context.AttachTo("Departments", holder);

        context.DeleteObject(holder);

        int numOfObjectsAffected = context.SaveChanges();
        returnValue = numOfObjectsAffected;

        context.Dispose();
    }

    return returnValue;

}
```

Comment: Last 4 lines should be just this: return context.SaveChanges();. Also remove returnValue variable. Why create so much useless noise in code?

Comment: Some frameworks return the object that was removed. ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int) )  Some frameworks return a bool if the method worked.  Some frameworks return the number of rows affected.  Some frameworks return void.  Just because you wouldn't do it, doesn't mean there isn't a legitimate need for it.  But yes, my code could be slimmed by using "returnValue = context.SaveChanges();".  (<<Just to show that I am not unteachable.)  Yes, if you pick at it, you could remove some more code.  Sometimes readability is preferred over conciseness.

Comment: Yes, readibility. This code is as ugly as possible. And not readable. That's what I meant.

Comment: Yes.  You are 100% correct.  It is the ugliest code on the internet.  And it is not readable.  No one could ever figure out what I was trying to do in my code.  Completely 100% unreadable.  You are 100% right.  You will always be 100% right.  I bow to your "rightness".  Thank you for taking time to correct me.  I am honored by your comments, that you would even think of me.  The funny thing is I used to work with a 30-something guy from Poland named Lukasz.  And he was very nice and encouraging.   ( http://lightshouse.org/lights-blog/why-its-smart-to-let-toxic-people-have-the-last-word )

Answer (score 1):

The disgustingly terrible hack I used is this:

```
var attachedObject = _repository.GetObjectByKey(detachedObject.EntityKey);
```

Works for a lot of these issues. I was hoping to find a more elegant solution to this problem by coming here. This seems to do the trick.