# Invalid operation exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to delete the record from an entity

got an error: Invalid operation exception
The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

and the code is like this...

```
private void btnProdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
    byte[] bit = null;
```

```
bit = imageToByteArray(image);

//var c = new category {
//  category_Name = tbCategoryName.Text,
//  category_Description = tbCategoryDescription.Text
//};

product pd = new product();
pd.product_Id = productid;
pd.product_Name = tbProductName.Text;
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbProductPrice.Text);
pd.product_Price = price;
pd.product_Description = tbProductdescription.Text;
pd.product_Image = bit;

tsgentity.DeleteObject(pd);
this.Close();
```

}

would any one pls help on this...

**Modified code** :

```
public partial class ProductDescriptionForm : Form {
    public TsgEntities tsgentity;
    public ProductDescriptionForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        tsgentity = new TSGEntities();
    }
```

Comment: Where is `tsgentity` being initialized?  The error is indicating that the object that you are attempting to delete is not properly associated with the `ObjectContext`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Delete Object Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217052/entity-framework-delete-object-problem)

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a new entity and then trying to delete it...

Comment: so how to delete instead of creating new entity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to delete an object that is not tracked by the context.

The proper way to delete without fetching is to create an instance (only the id is actually needed), attach it to the context and then delete it :

```
var pd = 
    new product() 
    {
        product_Id = productid,
        EntityKey = new EntityKey("product.id", "id", productid)
    };
tsgentity.Attach(pd);
tsgentity.DeleteObject(pd);
```

Comment: now i am getting this error :An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context. at this line tsgentity.Attach(pd); would you pls look at this one ..

Comment: I've also updated my answer, but you might need to tweak it for your needs