# Linq to entity delete a specific column from a table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

Linq to entity query to delete a specific column from a table by matching a condition
`

```
public ActionResult deleteChecks(string checkValue)
    {
        check_master checks = (from table in db.check_master
                              where table.check_code == checkValue
                              select table).First();
        //now how to delete/remove checks.mcheck

        return View("Edit");
    }`
```

**Only want to update a single column element with null value(of selected row) from the table check_master**

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Linq to Entities only support DML, it does not support DDL operations.
So you would have to use stored procedure or ADO.NET raw query.

**EDIT**

you can do simple update like this :

```
public ActionResult deleteChecks(string checkValue)
{
    check_master checks = (from table in db.check_master
                          where table.check_code == checkValue
                          select table).First();

    checks.mcheck = null;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Edit");
}`
```

Comment: suppose i wish to delete a whole row 'checks' in our case then simply i can make a query that is like db.check_master.Remove(checks);.but here in my question i want to update my table matching(condition) row with "null" value for mcheck column

Comment: I am not sure I understand you... so you dont want do physically delete table column, you just want to set NULL in this column for all rows?

Comment: yes i don't want to delete a whole column i just want to update an element (selected) of that column. Say i have a column with values '1','2','4' now i want to update value '2' with NULL

Comment: oh, then your question is terribly misleading, please edit it and correct this! you dont want to DELETE anything - not even row, and certainly not column. you want simple UPDATE. See my answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework works with constant table scheme only.
Tell please, what your global aim is, may be there's some more suitable way to do it.

**Updated:**

```
foreach(var chm in db.check_master)
{
    chm.mcheck = null;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a single property (which maps to a column) to null and save it to the database

```
foreach(check_master check in checks)
{
   check.mcheck = null;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
```

{

```
// Retrieve the existing entity. Database Call 1

Product product = db.Products.First(p => p.ProductID == 1);



// Change the properties. LINQ to SQL knows

// these specific properties have changed.

product.UnitsInStock = 14;



// Flush the changes. Database Call 2

db.SubmitChanges();
```

}

Comment: What i am doing.....check_master checks = db.check_master.First(a=> a.check_code == checkValue);
            db.DeleteObject(checks);.....but in my controller there in no support to use DeleteObject(and even no intellisense)....Is i am missing to use any assembly in my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217052/entity-framework-delete-object-problem check this out

Comment: 'Using db As New HelloEfEntities

        Dim qStr = "Delete " & _
                  "FROM Employee"
        db.ExecuteStoreCommand(qStr)
        db.SaveChanges()
    End Using'