# asp.net VB Delete Multiple Rows in EF4

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework-4

I'm struggling with deleting multiple rows. I'm learning and have managed new rows and edits but cant seem to nail delete. Can someone help please?

this is what I have:

```
 If ViewState("QuoteGroupID") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim GQID As Integer = CInt(ViewState("QuoteGroupID"))
        Using db As New quotingSystemDevEntities
            Dim QuoteToDelete = (From q In db.QuotesGeneratedV2 Where q.QuoteGroupID = GQID Select q)
            db.DeleteObject(QuoteToDelete)
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
    End If
```

I'm getting the error "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Thanks you for your time.

---

### UPDATE

After much messing around I have figured it out. The info on the web was very difficult to make sense of so I went for the try everything until it works method... Might not be the perfect solution but it works better than the one that wasn't! Hopefully this info will help someone out:

```
 If ViewState("QuoteGroupID") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim GQID As Integer = CInt(ViewState("QuoteGroupID"))
        Using db As New quotingSystemDevEntities
            Dim QuoteToDelete = (From q In db.QuotesGeneratedV2 Where q.QuoteGroupID = GQID Select q)
            For Each item In QuoteToDelete
                db.Detach(item)
                db.Attach(item)
                db.DeleteObject(item)
            Next
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing [ObjectContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) Method. Try using that.

Also similar question can be found [Entity Framework Delete Object Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217052/entity-framework-delete-object-problem)

Comment: thanks for setting me on the correct path with .Attach and .Detach