# Entity framework not allowing me to delete a player

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to delete a row of data but it not allowing me. I am using entity framework. A Player can be in a team but a team can have many players. But all I am wanting to do is remove a player that is not part of a team I should be able to delete that without a problem,

I am using EF5 and asp.net 4 webforms

```
protected void grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

        player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);
        _dal.SoccerEntities.AddToplayers(_player);
        _dal.SoccerEntities.DeleteObject(_player);

        _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
        grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
        grdSoccerPlayers.Rebind();
    }
}
```

The Grid is being filleby using the following linq statement.

```
public IQueryable<player> getAllPlayers()
{
    var _player = SoccerEntities.players.ToList();
    return _player.AsQueryable();
}
```

This foreign key however is placed on teamID in the player table linking it to obv teams table. But I should be still able to just delete a player shouldnt I.? When i go to delete a team however that code works fine but not when i want to delete just a player. How can I over come this.

[image]

**When I remove the addtoplayers i get the following error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity, EntitySet expectedEntitySet) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(Object entity) at UniteCms.BackDoor.players._default.grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand(Object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) in c:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\UniteCms\BackDoor\players\default.aspx.cs:line 83

**I then attempted to sovle it by using the following**

[Entity Framework Delete Object Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217052/entity-framework-delete-object-problem)

But it gave the following error.

[Entity Framework Delete Object Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217052/entity-framework-delete-object-problem)

> System.InvalidOperationException: An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.Attach(IEntityWithKey entity) at UniteCms.BackDoor.players._default.grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand(Object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) in c:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\UniteCms\BackDoor\players\default.aspx.cs:line 83

Comment: What is your exception?

Comment: @hellogoodnight no exception the record just simply does not delete

Comment: @RameshBabu treied that doesnt work

Comment: @RameshBabu what code you have not suggested anything !

Comment: I am asking to post the code you have written for `DeleteObject` method

Comment: @RameshBabu i have not created any code this is EF DeleteObject I am using the standard not overidden!

Comment: @hellogoodnight still having issue here any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Ok For anyone else it seems ef does not like it when unique value is of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 as in null or empty guid once I took care of the roge record it appears to delete ok but its not display the fresh data on my grid till i refresh the page.

Code I end up using for anyone else is.

```
GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

   player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);
   _dal.SoccerEntities.Attach(_player);
   _dal.DeleteObject(_player);
   _dal.SaveChanges();
   grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
   grdSoccerPlayers.Rebind();
```